# D3.js tree resize to fit in SVG canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to resize my `d3.js` tree to its containing SVG. There are plenty of solutions online, but none of them seems to be working for my case.
I know (more or less) what to do when I manage to retrieve the size of the containing svg and the size of the contained tree, but my problem is that I have been having issues with retrieving the size of the tree.

I believe my issue comes from the fact that I am using `preserveAspectRatio` when creating the SVG. Here is the main part of the code:

```
var width  = 1500,
    height =  600;
var svg = d3.select('svg')
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
            .classed('svg-content-responsive', true);

zoombehavior = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.2, 5]).on('zoom', redraw);
svg.call(zoombehavior);

// Append title
svg.append('text');

// ...

// Append Legend
svg.append('g');

// ...

// Append Tree
var vis  = svg.append('svg:g').attr('class', 'vis');

var draw = vis.append('svg:g').attr('class', 'draw')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width-rectW)/2 + ',' + 100 + ')');
```

I am using this solution so that I am able to call `redraw` only on the `vis`, i.e. only on the visualized tree without affecting the title or the legend.

After that, I create the tree which is hierarchically below `draw`:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
           .nodeSize([rectW+20, rectH])
           .separation(function separation(a, b) {
              return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1.4);
            });
// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

// Declare the nodes.
var node = draw.selectAll('g.node');
```

Here is the first problem: my `svg` is responsive, which means that its actual size is different from the `width` and `height` that I assign in the beginning. E.g. on my monitor it is currently `2222 * 888`.

But, with a couple tricks, I managed to retrieve the actual position of the svg element:

```
var svgcnt = document.getElementById("svg-container");

var svgw = svgcnt.clientWidth;
var svgh = svgcnt.clientWidth * height / width;
```

Now, I need the size of the tree. Now, on most examples, I should call something like `draw.node().getBBox()` to get the size of the tree, but in my case the what I get in return is wrong.

For example, in my latest test I got `149.9820556640625 77` whereas the size of `draw` that is actually displayed (without any scaling) is `571 376`. This is both wrong in size, and importantly also in aspect ratio. For this reason, the function that I use to scale the tree (I am using [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshweir/75h6fuq5/) ) over-scales my tree. For completeness, here is also the full HTML DOM so that you can inspect it if needed:

```
<div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1500 600" class="svg-content-responsive">
        <text dx="750" dy="40" class="title filename" text-anchor="middle">icra</text>
        <g class="legendcnt" transform="translate(20,20)"></g>
        <g class="vis" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1)"><g class="draw">
            <path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M230,220C230,270 150,270 150,320"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M230,220C230,270 310,270 310,320"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,120C70,170 -90,170 -90,220"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,120C70,170 70,170 70,220"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,120C70,170 230,170 230,220"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,20C70,70 -90,70 -90,120"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,20C70,70 70,70 70,120"></path><path class="link" x="70" y="20" d="M70,20C70,70 230,70 230,120"></path><g class="node " transform="translate(160,100)"><rect width="110.37815856933594" height="40" class="label" x="14.810920715332031"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Mount Chair</text></g><g class="node human" transform="translate(240,300)"><rect width="86.00652313232422" height="40" class="label" x="26.99673843383789"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Place top</text></g><g class="node robot" transform="translate(80,300)"><rect width="79.91361236572266" height="40" class="label" x="30.043193817138672"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Take  top</text></g><g class="node " transform="translate(160,200)"><rect width="96.16136932373047" height="40" class="label" x="21.919315338134766"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Mount top</text><g class="combination"><rect width="36" height="36" x="52" y="41"></rect><text x="70" y="8" dy="2.2em" text-anchor="middle">→</text></g></g><g class="node  collapsed" transform="translate(0,200)"><rect width="99.20782470703125" height="40" class="label" x="20.396087646484375"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Mount legs</text><g class="combination"><rect width="36" height="36" x="52" y="41"></rect><text x="70" y="8" dy="2.2em" text-anchor="middle">||</text></g></g><g class="node robot" transform="translate(-160,200)"><rect width="149.98207092285156" height="40" class="label" x="-4.991035461425781"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Take central frame</text></g><g class="node " transform="translate(0,100)"><rect width="108.3471908569336" height="40" class="label" x="15.826404571533203"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Mount Stool</text><g class="combination"><rect width="36" height="36" x="52" y="41"></rect><text x="70" y="8" dy="2.2em" text-anchor="middle">→</text></g></g><g class="node " transform="translate(-160,100)"><rect width="115.4555892944336" height="40" class="label" x="12.272205352783203"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Mount Bench</text></g><g class="node " transform="translate(0,0)"><rect width="124.5949478149414" height="40" class="label" x="7.702526092529297"></rect><text x="70" y="20" dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle">Available Tasks</text><g class="combination"><rect width="36" height="36" x="52" y="41"></rect><text x="70" y="8" dy="2.2em" text-anchor="middle">v</text></g></g></g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?